# How do I style Wordpress pages differently based on the tag used?

Tags: css, tags, page-template, conditional-tags

I was thinking this might be done by adding custom CSS to a page template. I have a page template like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Grafy Full Width
 */

/*add_filter('materialis_full_width_page', '__return_true');*/

materialis_get_header();
?>
    <div <?php echo materialis_page_content_atts(); ?>>
        <div class="grafy-full-width-content">
            <?php
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                the_content();
            endwhile;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And I thought I might be able to add the CSS like this (basically I have 10 main tags and all I need to do is to change the header background, so I might just add 10 one-lined CSS files and condition them like this):

```
<?php function wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles() {
    if (has_tag('Lesy')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'Lesy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/Lesy.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles' );?>
```

No matter what I do, this just isn't working. What could I be doing wrong? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the `body_class` and `post_class` template tags, you get a CSS class added that contains classes for all the tags and terms a post has  which you can use to conditionally style posts without needing to conditionally enqueue stylesheets

Comment: Great idea, it's working like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `has_tag` outside of the loop. You must add the post ID to `has_tag`. I also add `property_exists` to be sure we have a post object and avoid warnings.

```
function wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles() {
    global $post;

    if (property_exists($post, 'ID') === true && has_tag('Lesy', $post->ID)) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'Lesy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/Lesy.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles' );
```